# Debugging which script is causing a cookie deletion

Tags: javascript, cookies, firebug

I've got a cookie on the website I'm working on, which is created on page load and then deleted straight after. I'm trying to ascertain which script is causing the cookie to be removed.

I'm using Firebug and can see the cookie creation and deletion within the cookie section of the console log. However I can't set a breakpoint on the actual cookie as it doesn't exist when I go in to inspect the site's cookies.

I have tried creating it manually, adding a breakpoint and then reloading page, however this doesn't seem to do anything.

I don't think breaking on all cookie changes is viable, as from the log the site seems to generate several hundred cookie changes on page load. (No idea why, I did not create any of this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two ways how to find out where the cookie gets removed.

1. **Search for 'document.cookie'**

   If the cookie gets removed via JavaScript, you should be able to find it within the code by searching for `document.cookie` in the *Script* panel (ensure that the search option *Multiple Files* is checked).

   *Note: This assumes that the statement appears like this within the code, i.e. it is not minimized or looks different (like e.g. `document['cookie']`).*
2. **Set a cookie breakpoint**

   As you write, the cookie is created on page load. So, set a breakpoint within the load event handler and then step debug to the line where the cookie is created.

   Once the cookie is created, switch to the *Cookies* panel and create a breakpoint for the cookie.

   Then continue the script execution (e.g. by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>).

   The script execution should then stop at the line where the cookie is removed.